# Reading Floats from Text file works until out of ifstream scope c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io, floating-point

I'm trying to read in floats from a file with exactly 70x50 numbers into a 2D array. When I read in the file and cout the data in the array, I get the correct numbers. But when I try to use the data in my array after I read in the file, then the data is gibberish. Do I need to allocate heap memory to persist after the file is read? Code is below:

```
int main() {

fstream file("numbers.txt");
if (!file) {
    cerr << "Sample data could not be opened" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(1);
}


float data[70][50];
for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        float n;
        file>> n;
        data[i][j] = n;
        cout << data[i][j];
    }
}

cout << data[70][50];
system("PAUSE");
face.close();

return(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will produce undefined behavior

```
cout << data[70][50];
```

The array has dimensions `[70][50]`, meaning the last valid indices are `[69][49]`.

To directly answer your question of:

> Do I need to allocate heap memory to persist after the file is read?

No. Your array `data` is perfectly fine. If you were to loop over it and `cout` all the values from `[0][0]` to `[69][49]` you would notice that the values will be correct.

Comment: Ahh moving from matlab to c++ and forgot the zero indexing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To print the entire contents of the whole array, you have to have a loop -- or two, in this case of a bidimensional array --, and print each of its elements.